# How to add created IP set to Web ACL using aws wafv2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-waf

I was able to create an IP set using aws wafv2, but I'm having trouble adding it to an existing Web ACL. Is there a way to add an IP set to a Web ACL using aws wafv2?

Answer (score -1):

A Web ACL and an IP set are not directly related resources in WAFv2. You can create a IPSetReferenceStatement rule referencing the IP set you created, and then add this rule to your Web ACL.

Comment: Could you provide more details about how to create an IPSetReferenceStatement rule in the form of either a command to run or with indications on how to create the rule?